# How to tell if a variable has effect in a linear model?

Tags: r, regression, lm

Suppose `df` is a dataframe which contains 5 variables

```
   price odometer age condition   city
8  11900    56000   6  like new boston
12  3250   157000  12      good     sf
14 15995    25815   3  like new     sf
16  3895   187398  13  like new     ny
17  2995   174753  16  like new boston
18 14900    49809   3 excellent boston
```

let price be my response variable, establish lm model, I did

```
mod <- lm(sqrt(price1) ~ odometer + age + condition + city, data = df, na.action = na.omit)
```

But how can I tell whether the city variable has effect on my lm model? Should I run another lm without including the city variable to compare with?

Comment: I think for such question you simply need use `summary.lm` and look at `Pr(>|t|)`

Answer (score 2):

As the user Batanichek pointed out, you should use the summary function:

```
summary(mod)
```

And now you will get a list of regression coefficients, standard errors, t values, and p-values. The last column, called `Pr(>|t|)`, gives you the p-values.

Since city is a categorical variable, you will get a number of different values for city in the output, eg. cityboston, citysf, cityny and so on. One of the cities (either the most frequent occurring city or the one that is first in alphabetical order) will serve as the reference to which the other cities are compared. If boston is the reference and citysf has a regression coefficient of 50, it means that the square root of price in sf is 50 higher than in boston, when all other variables are taken into consideration.

Perhaps you knew this already and simply want to see if the city variable contributes significantly to your model. In that case, you can do this:

```
anova(mod)
```

The output will compare the full model to all models that drop one of the variables, and the `Pr(>F)` column will tell you whether each variable contributes significantly to the model or not.